# A term / title that describes "metadata" details for knowledge base article

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on creating a knowledge base and want a section on each page to be essentially "metadata" for an article. Things like:

- Author name of article.
- Applicable product.
- Date the article was created.
- Version (or date when the article was last modified).

The term "Metadata" isn't easily understood by readers. "Author Information" isn't quite right either since it's not JUST information about the author. "Article Details" or "Article Information" seems like it could be confused with the actual article itself.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: *About*......... Just like in your browser menu: it tells you info about the browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to call it *About this Article*. It's straightforward and describes the contents of the information you wish to present.

Also, this metadata sounds a lot like what would go in the contents of a citation. Though this isn't what you might have had in mind, you could categorize this information under a *citation* header.